# ignore .htaccess (from Symfony2) for non SF apps

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I installed Symfony2 framework on a server that had many other php apps before that. The .htaccess that came with symfony now messes with the urls and I would kindly ask for some help to configure it correctly.

Before that I could call an app with url https://domain.com/fb_app/app_1/
and that url automatically called the index.php (or index.html) file.

Now I added the following lines in the SF .htaccess

```
# stuff to let through (ignore)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/fb_app/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

That is OK to some extent and it ignores the following folder (and subfolders) but if I want to run the same app I have to call the following url: https://domain.com/fb_app/app_1/index.php

But I need it to function without the index.php in the url!
Now it returns:
**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access ...**
if i don't include index.php in the url.

If I remove the .htaccess from public_html everything works back again (except my symfony app that is now broken :)

Comment: Maybe you have something like this in your virtualHost or your apache config: 
`DirectoryIndex app.php`

Comment: Can you move the symfony project to a subfolder? And make an index.php ```<?php header('Location: ./symfony_app_folder/'); ?>```

Comment: I don't want to do that. Found out that the problem is that .htaccess is redirecting to app.php instead of the index file on every url. If I rename index.php to app.php it works...